# How to represent geometry with values read from JSON file in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I've large group of five vertices in JSON which needs to represented as cone geometry shown below.

Five vertices: {(x,y,z) , (a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), (j,k,l) }, {(x1,y1,z1) , (a1,b1,c1), (d1,e1,f1), (g1,h1,i1), (j1,k1,l1) }..............

**NOTE: These cordinates are canvas cordinates.**

Here is the diagram:

[image: Cone]

where these vertex values are read from JSON file and needed to make a geometry. These vertex values are unique to every single geometry.

AFAIK, how to use three.js pre-defined geometry  and custom geometry like below code. My question is how to represent the geometry using the values read from JSON file?

```
    var cone;
    var geo = new THREE.Geometry();

    var meshMaterial = new new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff });

    geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(   0, 0, 0));
    geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -0.5, 0.5, 1));
    geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0.5, 0.5, 1));
    geo.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -0.5, -0.5, 1));
    geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 0.5,-0.5, 1));

   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(4,3,0));
   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(3,1,0));
   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(0,2,4));
   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(2,1,4));
   geo.faces.push( new THREE.Face3(1,3,4));

   geo.computeFaceNormals();
   cone = new THREE.Mesh(geo, meshMaterial);
   cone.doubleSided = true;
   cone.overdraw = true;

   //And finally we need (x,y,z) to set the position of this geometry to display on the canvas
   cone.position.set(x,y,z);
```

I've tried a lot, how to create geometry using values read from other files , But I didn't find anything, which initated me to post this question.

P.S: Among these values {(x,y,z) , (a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), (j,k,l) }, (x,y.z) should be position of the tip of the cone on the canvas while representing the cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the 81.214.75.32:8181/admin (wait for autoloding scene for a couple of seconds) see the page source and open FileManager.js included on top. Examine "importScene" function. That will help you alot with loading geometry data from a file and create models from vertice, normals, textures info.

Comment: hi, I am facing the similar problem in Three.js I also need to read the positions from local JSON file and populate them in Three JS Buffer Geometry_Point, could you please share your solution or can answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112211/load-positions-attribute-from-a-json-file-in-three-js-buffer-geometry-points